# Tizen webapp - Background service after app closed

Tags: web-applications, service, background, tizen

I'm developing an application that needs to set an alarm clock, the user enter the day and hour that it should play. I want to know if there is any kind of tizen "service" that keeps running in background even if the user close the application and if I can use it to implement this app as an WebApp.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Alarm](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/alarm.html) and [Application](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/application.html) APIs to relaunch the app at some specified time.

You can also see the [ExercisePlanner](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/sample_descriptions/exerciseplanner.htm) sample app which shows such usage.

Comment: Hey Paul, it seems like I will need to implement my application native because of other functions that the web don't support. Do you know it there is any examples like this one but in C that could help me understand the Alarm API Native. Thank you.

Comment: There are many native sample applications, this tutorial seems to show the usage of the Alarm native API https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/tutorials/system_tutorial/task_systemapp_alarm.htm